# Inserting to table in VB.NET, LINQ to SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq

This is the beginnings of a timetabling algorithm. The problem is with inserting a member into a group, but I have included the whole subroutine here for context. The table "membergroup" has 2 headings, MemberID and GroupID. No error code is thrown, but the table does not receive the new record.
I have gone through it line by line, and the values for iMember_Choice.MemberID and groupID_to_insert are correct.

```
Dim numberofrooms As Byte = rm.Count
    Dim possiblerooms(numberofrooms + 1), possibleroomcounter As Int32
    For TimeTableNumber = 1 To Val(NumberOfTimetablesToCreate.Text)
        Dim memchoic = (dc.ExecuteQuery(Of memberChoice)("SELECT * FROM MemberChoices ORDER BY NEWID()")).ToList 'Orders list randomly
        'sort into array for each rank, so highest ranks are allocated first
        Dim Member_choices_Table_ordered_by_rank = From q In memchoic Order By q.Rank
        For Each Member_Choice In Member_choices_Table_ordered_by_rank
            ProgressBar.Value = ProgressBar.Value + 1
            Dim iMember_Choice As memberChoice = Member_Choice
            'Dim memactpossibleinstance(maxmemchoicernk, n) As memactvpossibleinstance
            For Each room In rm
                Dim rmid As Int32 = room.RoomID ' finds rooms activities can be in
                If Not (From rom In roomact Where rom.ActivityID = iMember_Choice.ActivityID And rom.RoomID = rmid).FirstOrDefault Is Nothing Then 'finds suitable rooms
                    possiblerooms(possibleroomcounter) = rmid
                    possibleroomcounter = possibleroomcounter + 1
                End If
            Next
            'find possible times
            Dim roomid_to_insert, current_maximum_rank As Integer
            Dim period_to_insert As String = "MonAM"
            Dim staffact_that_can_do_this_activity = _
                                        (From q In staffact Where q.ActivityID = iMember_Choice.ActivityID)
            For roomcount = 0 To possibleroomcounter - 1 'for each room in roomcount, find rank for room
                Dim rmid As Int32 = possiblerooms(roomcount)

                For Each time In periods
                    Dim itime As String = time.Period
                    Dim Rank As Int16 = member_Error_check_period_count(iMember_Choice.MemberID, itime)
                    If Not (From rav In rmav Where rav.RoomID = rmid And rav.Period = itime) Is Nothing Then 'room is free
                        Rank = Rank + 12
                    Else ' room has an activity
                        Dim GroupID_now = (From q In instnce Where q.Period = itime And q.RoomID = rmid Select q.GroupID).SingleOrDefault
                        If GroupID_now <> 0 Then
                            Dim groupActID_now = (From q In grp Where q.GroupID = GroupID_now Select q.ActivityID).SingleOrDefault
                            'Dim activity_now = (From q In actv Where q.ActivityID = groupActID_now).SingleOrDefault
                            If groupActID_now = iMember_Choice.ActivityID Then 'Good, this activity is already on in this room
                                Rank = Rank + 50
                                If (From q In memgrp Where q.GroupID = GroupID_now).Count > 4 Then
                                    Rank = Rank - 50
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                    If Rank > current_maximum_rank Then
                        current_maximum_rank = Rank
                        roomid_to_insert = rmid
                        period_to_insert = itime
                    End If
                    Rank = 0
                Next
                possibleroomcounter = 0


            Next 'for each room possible
            Dim groupID_to_insert As Integer
            If (From q In instnce Where q.Period = period_to_insert And q.RoomID = roomid_to_insert).FirstOrDefault Is Nothing Then
                groupID_to_insert = insert_ins_group(period_to_insert, roomid_to_insert, iMember_Choice.ActivityID)
            Else
                groupID_to_insert = (From q In instnce Where q.Period = period_to_insert And q.RoomID = roomid_to_insert Select q.GroupID).SingleOrDefault
            End If
'PROBLEM PROBPBLY HERE/////////////////////////////////////
            memgrp.InsertOnSubmit(New membergroup With {.MemberID = iMember_Choice.MemberID, .GroupID = groupID_to_insert})  'PROBLEM PROBABLY HERE
            dc.SubmitChanges()
            current_maximum_rank = 0
        Next 'for each memberchoice
        dc.SubmitChanges()

    Next 'timetabl no
    dc.SubmitChanges()
```

memgrp is initiated as

```
Dim memgrp As Table(Of membergroup) = dc.GetTable(Of membergroup)()
```

Comment: Where is `memgrp` instantiated? Is it associated with the same context instance as `dc`? Don't call `SubmitChanges` multiple times. LINQ to SQL uses the unit of work pattern. Queue up all of the work you want to do and call `SubmitChanges` once at the end.

Comment: Normally I would not, but I wanted to check if that was the problem. it does not work if I take the last 2 away. I have to call dc.submitchanges there, so that when it checks for conflicts as it goes back around the loop, the new record is there for it to find.